# init.d script does not work unless the same script is executed from a local directory first

Tags: python, shell, raspbian, init.d

I have run into a problem that I still haven't been able to solve despite hours of efforts including searching numerous Linux forums. My init.d script is based on a standard script to launch a python script  as a service. I have used this script for other services without any problems, but not this time.

To make a long story short, my problem is like follows:

The script works fine if I execute it in my home directory. I can start and stop the service etc.

If I execute the script in /etc/init.d it also works fine, *provided I have run it once before in my home directory*. If I try to execute the script immidiately after reboot, nothing happens. Consequently the service does not start after reboot. Running the script with service "script_name" start/stop/restart follows the same pattern. Ok if I have executed the script from my home directory first, otherwise nothing happens.

I get a feeling it is related to the environment, but if I check with printenv before and after executing the script from my home directory I can't see anything has changed. There are no other things that I believe is changed by running the script from my home directory. I run the script with sudo.

Since the script is exactly the same as I use on another Rasp except for the name of the Python script (and it works there...), I hardly believe there is something wrong in the script.

EDIT: I just noticed I can log off/on and this does not affect the status. So I can still run it in /etc/init.d if I've made it work by executing it once from my home directory since last reboot. Here comes the script:

```
#! /bin/bash
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          bbb_domoticz
# Required-Start:    $network $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $network $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: BehovsBoBox control script

# Description:       This daemon will start the BehovsBoBox Control system
### END INIT INFO

# Do NOT "set -e"


PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
DESC="BehovsBoBox Control System"
NAME=bbb_domoticz.py
USERNAME=pi

DAEMON=/home/pi/bbb_addon/$NAME
DEAMON_OPTS=""

PIDFILE=/var/run/bbb_domoticz.pid
#
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/bbb_domoticz.sh



#
# Modified to force deamon to execute in background
#

# Exit if the package is not installed
# [ -x "$DAEMON" ] || exit 0

# Load the VERBOSE setting and other rcS variables
. /lib/init/vars.sh
VERBOSE=""

# Define LSB log_* functions.
# Depend on lsb-base (>= 3.2-14) to ensure that this file is present
# and status_of_proc is working.
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

#
# Function that starts the daemon/service
#
do_start()
{
        # Return
        #   0 if daemon has been started
        #   1 if daemon was already running
        #   2 if daemon could not be started
        if [ -e $PIDFILE ]
        then 
          pid=$(<$PIDFILE)
          ps p $pid > /dev/null || rm -f $PIDFILE
        fi
#        start-stop-daemon --chuid $USERNAME --start  --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON --test > /dev/null \
#                || return 1
#        echo "OK to start"
        start-stop-daemon --start  --make-pidfile --pidfile $PIDFILE   --background --startas $DAEMON -- $DEAMON_OPTS || return 2
}

#
# Function that stops the daemon/service
#
do_stop()
{
        # Return
        #   0 if daemon has been stopped
        #   1 if daemon was already stopped
        #   2 if daemon could not be stopped
        #   other if a failure occurred
        start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --retry=TERM/30/KILL/5 --pidfile $PIDFILE
        RETVAL="$?"
        [ "$RETVAL" = 2 ] && return 2
        # Wait for children to finish too if this is a daemon that forks
        # and if the daemon is only ever run from this initscript.
        # If the above conditions are not satisfied then add some other code
        # that waits for the process to drop all resources that could be
        # needed by services started subsequently.  A last resort is to
        # sleep for some time.
        start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --retry=0/30/KILL/5 --exec $DAEMON
        [ "$?" = 2 ] && return 2
        # Many daemons don't delete their pidfiles when they exit.
        rm -f $PIDFILE
        return "$RETVAL"
}

case "$1" in
  start)
        [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$NAME"
        do_start
#        echo "status $?"
        case "$?" in
                0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
                2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
        esac
        ;;
  stop)
        [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC" "$NAME"
        do_stop
        case "$?" in
                0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
                2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
        esac
        ;;
  status)
        status_of_proc "$DAEMON" "$NAME" && exit 0 || exit $?
        ;;
  restart)
        log_daemon_msg "Restarting $DESC" "$NAME"
        do_stop
        case "$?" in
          0|1)
                do_start
                case "$?" in
                        0) log_end_msg 0 ;;
                        1) log_end_msg 1 ;; # Old process is still running
                        *) log_end_msg 1 ;; # Failed to start
                esac
                ;;
          *)
                # Failed to stop
                log_end_msg 1
                ;;
        esac
        ;;
  *)
        echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|status|restart}" >&2
        exit 3
        ;;
esac

:
```

Comment: The obvious thing to check is that all filenames are full, not relative, and you don't rely on environment variables (PYTHONPATH?) that are not present in the init.d environment.  Only working the second time is strange, unless it relies on a daemon which should already be running.  It could just be that you need to alter the run order.

Comment: please share the script - so we'll be able to review it

Comment: In **do_start()** nothing happens unless the **[ -e $PIDFILE ]** is true, $PIDFILE is earlier set to */var/run/bbb_domoticz.pid*.  Does that file really exist on bootup?

Comment: The if statement ends before start-stop-daemon. So this is not the problem. That part works fine. It's just a measure to clean-up an old PID-file if such one exists, but with a PID of a non-existing process.

Comment: I turns out the problem is associated with the daemon (python script), not the init.d script. I made a copy of the init.d script, but changed daemon to an extremely simple script, just a loop with a wait-command.  This daemon starts perfectly at boot ( as expected). But not the real daemon. In syslog I can find entries from both init.d scripts

Comment: "Starting ....: <daemon-1>" and "Starting .....: <daemon-2>". But that's it. Nothing more. And I have dedicated log-file written by the daemon with python logger support. Nothing there either. So my taking is the daemon does not start or exits silently.

Comment: Problem pinpointed to a method openurl in url2lib. Invoked early in the daemon. If the daemon is launched by boot or by service <daemon> start,  the daemon terminate without any traceback, message or anything else, when this method is called. If I start the daemn by running the script from my home directory, everything works fine, and subsequent service start/stop command work as well. Really strange....